# Method not being resolved for dynamic generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I have these types:

```
public class GenericDao<T>
{
    public T Save(T t)
    {            
        return t;
    }
}

public abstract class DomainObject {
    // Some properties

    protected abstract dynamic Dao { get; }

    public virtual void Save() {
        var dao = Dao;
        dao.Save(this);
    }
}

public class Attachment : DomainObject
{
    protected dynamic Dao { get { return new GenericDao<Attachment>(); } }
}
```

Then when I run this code it fails with RuntimeBinderException: Best overloaded method match for 'GenericDAO<Attachment>.Save(Attachment)' has some invalid arguments

```
var obj = new Attachment() { /* set properties */ };
obj.Save();
```

I've verified that in DomainObject.Save() "this" is definitely Attachment, so the error doesn't really make sense. Can anyone shed some light on why the method isn't resolving?

Some more information - It succeeds if I change the contents of DomainObject.Save() to use reflection:

```
public virtual void Save() {
    var dao = Dao;
    var type = dao.GetType();
    var save = ((Type)type).GetMethod("Save");
    save.Invoke(dao, new []{this});
}
```

Comment: Investigate this. Don't know the reason, so I won't post as an answer, but I think the problem is with `this`. In your virtual `Save` method, I played with it, added `dynamic obj = this; dao.Save(obj);` and it resolved at runtime. Test it to see that it actually functions given your code.

Comment: @Ani, I updated his code to something that compiles but still exhibits his runtime broken behavior. It's an interesting question.

Comment: @Anthony, Can you please re-post your comment as an answer so I can mark it? It does seem to work to do dynamic obj = this; dao.Save(obj);  Also, can anyone explain why this works? is it a bug in the DLR?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that some aspects of the dynamic method-call are resolved at compile-time. This is by design. From the language specification (emphasis mine):

> **7.2.3 Types of constituent expressions**
>
> When an operation is statically bound,
> the type of a constituent expression
> (e.g. a receiver, and argument, an
> index or an operand) is always
> considered to be the compile-time type
> of that expression. When an operation
> is dynamically bound, the type of a
> constituent expression is determined
> in different ways depending on the
> compile-time type of the constituent
> expression:
>
> • A constituent expression
> of compile-time type dynamic is
> considered to have the type of the
> actual value that the expression
> evaluates to at runtime
>
> • A
> constituent expression whose
> compile-time type is a type parameter
> is considered to have the type which
> the type parameter is bound to at
> runtime
>
> • **Otherwise the constituent
> expression is considered to have its
> compile-time type.**

Here, the constituent expression `this` has a compile-time type `DomainObject<int>` (simplification: the source-code is in a generic type, so that complicates how we should "view" the compile-time type of `this`, but hopefully, what I mean is understood), and since this is not of type dynamic or a type-parameter, **its type is taken as its compile-time type**.

So the binder looks for a method `Save` taking a single parameter of type `DomainObject<int>` (or to which it would have been legal to pass an object of type `DomainObject<int>` at compile-time).

It would have looked *somewhat* like this had the binding happened at compile-time:

```
// Extra casts added to highlight the error at the correct location. 
// (This isn't *exactly* what happens.)
DomainObject<int> o = (DomainObject<int>) (object)this;
GenericDao<Attachment> dao = (GenericDao<Attachment>)Dao;

// Compile-time error here. 
// A cast is attempted from DomainObject<int> -> Attachment.
dao.Save(o);
```

But this can't work since the only candidate-method of concern on `GenericDao<Attachment>` is `Attachment Save(Attachment)`, and for this method, no implicit conversion exists from type of the argument (`DomainObject<int>`) to the type of the parameter (`Attachment`).

So we get the compile-time error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'GenericDao<Attachment>.Save(Attachment)' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DomainObject<int>' to 'Attachment'
```

And *this* is the error that is deferred until run-time with the `dynamic` version. Reflection doesn't have the same problem because it doesn't attempt to extract "partial" information about the method-call at compile-time, unlike the `dynamic` version.

Fortunately, the fix is simple, defer the evaluation of the type of the constituent-expression:

```
dao.Save((dynamic)this);
```

This moves us into option 1 (compile-time type `dynamic`). The **type of the constituent-expression is deferred until run-time**, and this helps us bind to the right method. Then the statically-bound equivalent of the code is something like:

```
// Extra casts added to get this to compile from a generic type
Attachment o = (Attachment)(object)this;
GenericDao<Attachment> dao  = (GenericDao<Attachment>)Dao;

// No problem, the Save method on GenericDao<Attachment> 
// takes a single parameter of type Attachment.
dao.Save(o);
```

which should work fine.

Comment: Thank you this clarifies the behavior. Very interesting!

Answer (score 14):

Ani's answer is quite fine; Ani asked me to add some extra explanatory text at my discretion, so here you go.

Basically what's going on here is that a dynamic invocation where *some* of the arguments are not dynamic causes the dynamic analysis to honour the compile-time information that was known.  That's maybe not clear without an example. Consider the following overloads:

```
static void M(Animal x, Animal y) {}
static void M(Animal x, Tiger y) {}
static void M(Giraffe x, Tiger y) {}
...
dynamic ddd = new Tiger();
Animal aaa = new Giraffe();
M(aaa, ddd);
```

What happens?  We have to do a dynamic invocation, so the *runtime type* of ddd is used to do overload resolution. But aaa is not dynamic, so its *compile time type* is used to do overload resolution.  At runtime the analyzer tries to solve this problem:

```
M((Animal)aaa, (Tiger)ddd);
```

and chooses the *second* overload. It does not say "well, at runtime aaa is Giraffe, therefore I should be solving the problem:

```
M((Giraffe)aaa, (Tiger)ddd);
```

and choose the third overload.

The same thing is happening here. When you say

```
dao.Save(this)
```

the compile-time type of dao is "dynamic", but the compile-time type of "this" is not. Therefore when solving the overload resolution problem at runtime, we use the runtime type of "dao" but the compile-time type of the argument.  The compiler would have given an error for that combination of types, and therefore so does the runtime binder.  Remember, the runtime binder's job is to tell you *what would the compiler have said if it had all the information available about everything that was marked 'dynamic'*. The runtime binder's job is not to change the semantics of C# to make C# a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 2):

Quite good answers here already. I ran into the same problem. You're right reflection does work. Because you are specifying the type by saying GetType() which gets resolved at runtime.

```
var method = ((object)this).GetType().GetMethod("Apply", new Type[] { @event.GetType() }); //Find the right method
            method.Invoke(this, new object[] { @event }); //invoke with the event as argument
```

Or we can use dynamics as follows

```
    dynamic d = this;
    dynamic e = @event;
    d.Apply(e);
```

So in your case

```
public abstract class DomainObject {
    // Some properties

    protected abstract dynamic Dao { get; }

    public virtual void Save() {
        var dao = Dao;
        dynamic d = this; //Forces type for Save() to be resolved at runtime
        dao.Save(d);
    }
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

The code is confusing. I see two possible options here.

Dao is actually the parent of GenericDao because otherwise your getter has type mismatch:

```
public class Dao 
{
    void Save();
}

public class GenericDao<T> : Dao
{
    public virtual T Save(T) {...}
}

// error here because GenericDao does not implement Dao.
protected dynamic Dao { get { return new GenericDAO<Attachment>(); } }
```

Alternatively, Dao may be a child of GenericDAO. But in this case the getter is not correct either and the situation is actually worse.

So the bottom line is that there is a problem with your class/interface hierarchy. Please clarify and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: The code is updated so it should compile. Does it make more sense now?