# Calling `Contains` method from C# dynamic type yields error - why?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection

I simplified my problem into a tiny program which examples the exact error I receive during run-time.

You can copy-paste it into a console application and see for yourself.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<MyDataClass>()
            {
                new MyDataClass {A = 1, B = 1},
                new MyDataClass {A = 3, B = 8}
            };
            var ops = new MyOperationsClass();
            ops.ReallyGreatOperation(list, list[0]);
        }
    }

    public class MyDataClass
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }

        public void AddDataPartsToEachOther()
        {
            var c = A + B;
            A = c;
            B = c;
        }
    }

    public class MyOperationsClass
    {
        public void ReallyGreatOperation(object obj, object z)
        {
            dynamic x = obj;
            if (x.Contains(z)) //<-- gets an error here..
                ((dynamic)z).AddDataPartsToEachOther();
        }
    }
}
```

So what is really the problem?

As I understand `dynamic` keyword can be used as a wildcard, if a method exists it will be called with no problem. so why is it not working for me in this scenario?

Now, I know that I can change it to work by doing this:

```
public class MyOperationsClass
{
    public void ReallyGreatOperation(object obj, object z)
    {
        dynamic x = obj;
    //    if (x.Contains(z)) //<-- gets an error here..
    //        ((dynamic)z).AddDataPartsToEachOther();
        if (x.GetType().GetMethod("Contains").Invoke(obj, new[] {z}))
            ((dynamic)z).AddDataPartsToEachOther();
    }
}
```

But as I said - what I wish is to understand why the more "natural" way is not working.. cause if I do it the 2nd way out of no choice - I don't see the point of `dynamic` in the language anymore.

The actual error received:

**An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll**

**Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(ConsoleApplication5.MyDataClass)' has some invalid arguments**

For those who may find it relevant I add a snippet of my actual code:

```
case RelationNavigation.RelationNavigationMultiplicity.ManyToOne:
{
    var stringValue = dto.PropertiesData[relationNavigation.PropertyEnd.PropertyInfo.Name];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
        continue;

    dynamic list = relationNavigation.PropertyEnd.PropertyInfo.GetValue(modelObj);

    var relatedModelIds = stringValue.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    foreach (var relatedModelId in relatedModelIds)
    {
        var relatedModel = GetById(relationNavigation.PropertyEnd.RelatedType, relatedModelId);
        if (relatedModel == null)
            continue;

        if(!list.GetType().GetMethod("Contains").Invoke(list, new[] { relatedModel }))
        //if (!list.Contains(relatedModel))
            list.Add(relatedModel);
        relationNavigation.RelatedObjectPropertyEnd.PropertyInfo.SetValue(relatedModel, modelObj);
    }
    break;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @sstan will add that..

Comment: what types have obj and z on runtime? I know it will not be fixed, just an example of these types when you get the exception.

Comment: You will find an explanation to your problem here: [Method not being resolved for dynamic generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674564/method-not-being-resolved-for-dynamic-generic-type).  And it also includes the solution, which is to cast `z` to dynamic: `if (x.Contains((dynamic)z))`.  But for what it's worth, it's best to look for non-dynamic solutions if possible.

Comment: I edited my answer did you take a look at it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (x.Contains(z))
```

you need to cast `z` to `dynamic`:

```
if (x.Contains((dynamic)z))
```

For more information on why this is needed, see here: [Method not being resolved for dynamic generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674564/method-not-being-resolved-for-dynamic-generic-type), which I think this question is a duplicate of.

That said, using `dynamic` is generally bad design. There is usually a better way using generics and/or interfaces.

Comment: @G.Y ??? I don't understand why do you accepted this answer. Gusman was telling you exactly the same thing much earlier. --- But I don't have to understand everything.

Comment: @Verarind this answer was more accurate solution to the problem I presented. but no worries i'll make sure to give Gusman rep boost in other ways ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have your function parameters defined as object, if you change your parameters to be also dynamic it will work:

```
public void ReallyGreatOperation(dynamic obj, dynamic z)
{
    if (obj.Contains(z))
        z.AddDataPartsToEachOther();
}
```

Here is a very small test program:

```
class Program
{
    static bool test(dynamic d, dynamic c)
    {
        return d.Contains(c);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test(new List<string>(), "not found"));

    }

}
```

Comment: But I need to have object - as in the real program the object is obtained from Reflection-GetValue which returns an object.

Comment: if the parameter is dynamic you can pass anything, that's the meaning for dynamic :)

Comment: @Gusman: I think you misundertand OP's problem.  OP gets the error at runtime, not at compile time.  `obj` gets cast to `x`, which is dynamic, before invoking `Contains`.  So I don't think your answer applies here.

Comment: Well, he added before a CS error from compilation and it has been removed... anyway, doing this it works, I'm going to add a test program here what I used to check this will work.

Comment: +1 for letting me know dynamic in the method signature will solve it for the example program - but as i mentioned I can not do that in the real program.

Comment: @G.Y but why you can't? I don't understand. you stated you got an object in your real program, you can pass that object to this function and it should work.

Comment: @Gusman please check this out and you'll understand me better.. http://pastebin.com/UX6ugaDm

Comment: @G.Y Ok, checked it and I get it, buuuttt.. that works... check this paste bin, it has an example program doing exactly what you're doing, you must have an error on the types of the objects: http://pastebin.com/XCh82mhm

Comment: Thanks, after seeing sstan answer I understood yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use the as operator, maybe you want to check x for null.

```
    public class MyOperationsClass
    {
        public void ReallyGreatOperation(object obj, object z)
        {
            List<MyDataClass> x = obj as List<MyDataClass>;
            if (x.Contains(z))
                ((dynamic)z).AddDataPartsToEachOther();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**
Another approach would be to cast your object to IList.

```
    public class MyOperationsClass
    {
        public void ReallyGreatOperation(object obj, object z)
        {
            IList list = obj as IList;
            if (list.Contains(z))
                ((dynamic)z).AddDataPartsToEachOther();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `List<MyDataClass>` is unknown during runtime.. can't use it inside MyOperationsClass

Comment: But its not necessarily a list.. in my real program the true type is `Hashset<T>` which not derive `IList` yet it does implements `Contains(T Item)` method.