# .NET6/EF: The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<...>.Add(...)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: dynamic, casting, entity-framework-core, type-conversion, .net-6.0

I'm working on a generic code to add .NET 6 Entity Framework DbSet<...> records, deserialized from JSON strings. The original code is (much) more elaborated, below are just samples to demonstrated the issue - the following method:

```
public static void AddRecord(dynamic dbSet, Type entityType, string json)
{
    var dataRecord = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, entityType);
    dbSet.Add(dataRecord);
}
```

results in a run-time error at `dbSet.Add(dataRecord)` call:

```
"The best overloaded method match for
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Northwind.Models.Category>.Add
(Northwind.Models.Category)' has some invalid arguments"}
...
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2<T0, T1>
(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, T0, T1)
```

if you call it, e.g., this way:

```
using (var ctx = ...)
{
  ...
  var json = ...
  ...
  AddRecord(ctx.Categories, typeof(Category), json);
}
```

I have intentionally, for clarity, used in the above code concrete dbSet (ctx.Categories) and compile time typedef (typeof(Category)) - in actual code these are run-time defined variables.

If you "unroll" the method code and write it this way:

```
using (var ctx = ...)
{
  ...
  var json = ...
  ...
  var dataRecord = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(Category));
  ctx.Categories.Add(dataRecord);
}
```

you would still get the mentioned above run-time error for the `.Add` method.

But if you write:

```
  var dataRecord = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Category>(json);
  ctx.Categories.Add(dataRecord);
```

or

```
  var dataRecord = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json);
  ctx.Categories.Add((Category)dataRecord);
```

the code will work without any issues.

Finally, an attemp to use `Convert.ChangeType` doesn't help:

```
  var dataRecord = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json);
  ctx.Categories.Add(Convert.ChangeType(dataRecord, typeof(Category)));
```

So, it looks like an explicit object type casting is compiled to and makes *on rum-time* some "special object interfaces arrangements", which dynamic object type casting doesn't?

**[Update]**

[Okan Karadag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848385/net6-ef-the-best-overloaded-method-match-for-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-db/73848562#73848562)'s prompt answer below gave me a hint how to change `AddRecord(...)` method to *workaround* the subject issue:

```
public static void AddRecord(DbContext dbContext, Type entityType, string json)
{
    var dataRecord = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, entityType);
    dbContext.Add(dataRecord);
}
```

This method works flawlessly. Although it doesn't answer the subject question, why the original `AddRecord(...)` method

```
public static void AddRecord(dynamic dbSet, Type entityType, string json)
{
    var dataRecord = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, entityType);
    dbSet.Add(dataRecord);
}
```

results in '`The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<...>.Add(...)' has some invalid arguments...`' runtime error at

```
   dbSet.Add(dataRecord);
```

code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic for dynamic.

```
public void AddEntity<T>(string json) where T:class
{
    var entity = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(entity);
    dbContext.Add<T>(entity);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675118/14671235) for problem error.

Comment: Thank you, your answer gave me a hint how to workaround the subject issue. Please see the _[Update]_ section I have just added to my original question.

Comment: @ShamilS I have added link for problem reason.